# php hextobin not works exactly in c#

Tags: c#, php, encoding, ascii, chr

I have following php code , I can't write c# code which exactly work as php. Looks there different encodings. I need write c# code which gives result as php code

My php code

```
echo hexbin('246439589af7f1d84eb638c995687d53');


    function hexbin($hexdata) {
      $bindata="";

      for ($i=0;$i<strlen($hexdata);$i+=2) {
        echo hexdec(substr($hexdata,$i,2)) ;

        $bindata.=chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata,$i,2)));
      }
      echo "<br>";
      return $bindata;
    }
```

Output

```
361005788154247241216781825620114910412583
$d9X����N�8ɕh}S
```

My c# code

```
public static void Main()
    {
        HexToBin("246439589af7f1d84eb638c995687d53");
    }

    static String HexToBin(string hexdata)
    {
        String bindata="";
        for (int i=0;i<hexdata.Length;i+=2) {
           Console.Write(Convert.ToInt64(hexdata.Substring(i,2), 16));
           bindata+= Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt64(hexdata.Substring(i,2), 16)).ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(bindata);
        return bindata;
    }
```

Output

```
361005788154247241216781825620114910412583
$d9X÷ñØN¶8Éh}S
```

I,m calculating hash_mac in  following code which gives different output

in php

```
hash_hmac('SHA1','123456', hexbin('246439589af7f1d84eb638c995687d53'));
```

in c#

```
static void hash_mac()
        {
           string  message = "123456";
            var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(HexToBin("246439589af7f1d84eb638c995687d53"));
            using (var hmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(keyByte))
            {
                hmacsha1.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(message));

                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", ByteToString(hmacsha1.Hash));
            }
        }
```

Comment: the output is the same, it's just that your php output has different encoding than your c# output (eg. one uses ascii, the other utf8, or something like that). if you're using binary data you shouldn't store it in a string but in a byte[].

Comment: but after this function I,m calculating hash_hmac, it gives different result

Comment: @Longoon12000 Thank you!!!!! 4-5 hours of searching for a solution

Answer (score 1):

After helps of Longoon12000 I fixed a code with following code.Storing and uses it as bytes.
It Works As I need

```
static void hash_mac()
        {
            message = "123456";
            using (var hmacsha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(StringToByteArray("246439589af7f1d84eb638c995687d53")))
            {
                hmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(message));

                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", ByteToString(hmacsha256.Hash));
            }
        }


        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
        {
            int NumberChars = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            return bytes;
        }
```